# Using functions in a class keeps returning NullPointerException error - Java

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I am having a weird issue where the function in my class keep returning NullPointerException, Here is my code below where I am referring to the cashRegister class and each time I use the functions (cashRegister.add() or cashRegister.toString()) it returns nullPointerException. Does anyone know how to fix?

```
private void sell() {
        Product product = product(readName());
        System.out.println("Selling " + product.getName());
        int number = readNumber();
        if (product.has(number)) {
            double sale = product.sell(number);
            cashRegister.add(sale);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not enough stock");
        }
    }
private void viewCash() {
    System.out.println(cashRegister.toString());
} 

import java.text.*;

public class CashRegister {
    private double cash;

    public CashRegister() {
    }

    public void add(double money) {
        cash += money;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cash: $" + formatted(cash);
    }

    private String formatted(double amount) {
        return new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where & how is your cash register instantiated? If you are getting an NPE, it means that it is not. Also, do not use double for money, use big decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,
You are neither instantiating your class nor passing its instance to the target function.

Comment: What does instantiating mean? How do I do that?

Comment: hmm, you have to do something like that CashRegister cashRegister = new CashRegister () somewhere in your code and pass it to either sell or view cash, e.g. for view cash methond it should be something like that:
private void viewCash(CashRegister cashRegister) {
    System.out.println(cashRegister.toString());
}

Comment: Here is the documentation about that - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Oh no I see now that you very much

Comment: @DMcCracken can you accept the answer and to close the question then?